# PHP - lost reference in object array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, reference

I have an array that stores some Employee Objects
ie.

```
var $this->employeeArray = array();
$this->employeeArray[] = $empObjectA;
$this->employeeArray[] = $empObjectB;
...
```

which Employee object has id, firstName, lastName etc.
I also have a function to search for the employee object that with certain ID. ie:

```
public function searchArrayByID($id) {
$targetObject = null;

        foreach($this->employeeArray as $e) {
            if ($id == $e->id) {
                $targetObject = $e;
                break;
            }
        }//foreach

return $targetObject;

}
```

but when I do:

```
$targetEmployee = $this->searchArrayByID(1);
$targetEmployee->firstName = "someOtherName";
```

and do a

```
print_r($this->employeeArray);
```

that object inside the Array is not being changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, with the `&` prepended, it will pass the reference.
i also simplified your search function.

Since i dont know why it isnt working for you, because its working for me on 2 different servers without any `&` i can just suggest the 'safest' method => force references wherever possible

```
$this->employeeArray[] = &$empObjectA;  // here

public function &searchArrayByID($id) {   // here
    foreach($this->employeeArray as &$e) {   // and here
        if ($id == $e->id) return $e;
    }
    return null;
}

$targetEmployee = $this->searchArrayByID(1);
```

now if that doesnt work, i suspect another error in your code, because every reference is forced here

funny thing is. i tried it here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2cv-pt2
and with that php version, it makes no difference (thats how it should be).
Which php version are you using? Because PHP got better at handling references (reducing unwanted/unnecessary copies)

Comment: unfortunately it's not working. I have used print_r on both $targetEmployee and $this->employeeArray. $targetEmployee contains the changes while the obj in $this->employeeArray doesn't

Comment: I'm using php 5.3.15 (mac)

Comment: plz tell me the php verion you are using, as i said, old php version are bad with reference, it tends to copy alot. and some manual referencing isnt allowed in newer version, thats why i cant tell what code will work for you

Comment: can you run this code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/890-j3a on your server? As you see on phpfiddle, it works fine, with and without the `&`'s. plz post the output of my code from your server

Comment: this is what I got: $obj1:
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => xyz
)
$emp1:
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => xyz
)
$obj2:
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => zui
)
$emp2:
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => zui
)
$empArr:
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => xyz
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => zui
        )

)    so when adding object to array I have to put an ampersand like: $this->array[] = &obj?

Comment: i dont know whats happening there for you, because my example seems to work for you with or without `&`. but i edited my code, try that, i hope it works

Comment: Yes, I have tried that out and it works on my local machine. I guess it must be something else. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: found out what caused the problem. It has nothing to do with the object reference. It's because my singleton object and my ajax request: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/393405/php-singletone-pattern-in-php-files-where-ajaxs-requests-are-sent so instead of returning the singleton object, each time I create a brand new object and that's why when I print out the array, my changes are gone

Answer (score 0):

That's because PHP copies the object to $targetEmployee, it's not linked.